# VSTO - Is it possible to have both designer and XML ribbons?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm working on an Outlook 2010 add-in that has multiple ribbons created with the Visual Studio 2010 ribbon designer. I've made an additional XML ribbon (I needed to override the default behavior of some built in ribbon buttons, which can't be done with the designer).

Enabling the XML ribbon disables all the designer ribbons because I have to override CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject (ContactButtonOverrides is my XML ribbon):

```
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
    return new ContactButtonOverrides();
}
```

The base class implementation I'm overriding "[returns a RibbonManager object that represents all Ribbon (Visual Designer) items in the project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.addinbase.createribbonextensibilityobject.aspx)".

Is there any way to use both XML ribbons and ribbons made with the designer? Is there some way of adding my XML ribbon to the default RibbonManager?

Comment: If you are interested please commit for this :http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/outlook-addin/commit

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no way to use both **Ribbon Designer** and **Ribbon XML** unless you use (2) separate add-ins. The [`IAddInExtension.CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee794652.aspx) is only called once for the life cycle of your add-in. You can either choose to implement the interface using the **Designer** or the **XML** route. They are two separate API hooks.

The **Ribbon Designer** is more of a crutch for those new to Office Ribbon development. [Once you get familiar with the **Ribbon XML** approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx) - it is much simpler and you have much more control over the behaviors (*as you indicate in your OP*). You can [migrate from Ribbon Designer to XML using the Context Menu from the Ribbon Designer surface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386297.aspx) - although there is some [rework for imagery and callbacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa942866.aspx) because the model is entirely different. It is worth your time to invest in **Ribbon XML** as it is the [only way to extend Context Menus (*`CommandBars` are deprecated*) and Backstage View as there is no designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

#### [Ribbon XML Route](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398246.aspx)

```cs
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
    {
        return new ContactButtonOverrides();
    }
```

Then within the `ContactButtonOverrides`...you can trigger which XML to load via [`IRibbonExtensibility.GetCustomUI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonextensibility.getcustomui%28v=office.14%29.aspx) which passes in the [Ribbon ID Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868522.aspx)...

```cs
public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
{
    switch (ribbonID)
    {
        case "Microsoft.Outlook.Appointment" : 
            return GetResourceText("OutlookRibbonApp.IPM.Appointment.Ribbon.xml");
        case "Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose" : 
            return GetResourceText("OutlookRibbonApp.IPM.Note.Ribbon.xml");
        default:
            return "";
    }
}
```

#### [Ribbon Designer Route](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386097.aspx#sectionToggle6)

```cs
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
    if (myCondition == true)
    {
        return Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonManager(
            new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.IRibbonExtension[] { new Ribbon1() });
    }
    else
    {
        return Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonManager(
            new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.IRibbonExtension[] { new Ribbon2() });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Just what I wanted to know.

Comment: It's a bit of a nuisance that context menus in Outlook 2013 are no longer supported using the `Application.ItemContextMenuDisplay` event, meaning you have to switch to XML, meaning you **also** have to migrate all ribbons from designer to XML.