# Multiple Ribbon XML in one Add-In

Tags: xml, outlook, ribbon

I want to have two Ribbon XML in one Outlook Add-In. Ribbon2 is a button in a context menu and Ribbon1 is a tab in Outlook Mail Read.
I did this -  [VSTO - Is it possible to have both designer and XML ribbons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216199/vsto-is-it-possible-to-have-both-designer-and-xml-ribbons), but then getLabel, getVisible, etc, doesn't work!
Can you please help me?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have solved my own problem. Just need to have the method called by getSomething in the ribbon that's created in ThisAddin!

**EDIT:**
However, it just works at the first time. Do you know why my Context Menu Ribbon updates/refreshes by itself but my Tab Ribbon doesn't? I've already tried Ribbon.Invalidated() and it didn't work for me... Please help!

**EDIT 2:**
I could do it using Ribbon.Invalidate()